# Oracle procedure: options to return data

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11gr2

I'm used to Microsoft SQL Server, where the last `SELECT` query of a stored procedure determines what is returned.

In Oracle, I'm always using a `SYS_REFCURSOR` `OUT` parameter to return data from queries.

**Are there other options of returning data from `SELECT` queries in Oracle stored procedures?**

How about `SELECT` queries that select only one row? Is a `SYS_REFCURSOR` still necessary?

**EDIT:** I need to know the answer for Oracle 11g R2 (should have mentioned that explicitly instead of just in the tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until now Oracle has not supported the SQL Server style of procedures implicitly returning a result set, you have had to explicitly return something - which could be a SYS_REFCURSOR or a collection or whatever.

In Oracle 12C a new feature has been added called [Implicit Statement Results](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/appdev.121/e17622/release_changes.htm#LNPLS118), which is designed to emulate the SQL Server way of working.  However, this is really intended to support migration of existing code from SQL Server; for fresh Oracle development you would be best advised to learn the way Oracle normally does things.

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean by *or a collection of whatever*?

Comment: I said "a collection *or* whatever", by which I just meant that there were many other options as per Nicolas Durand's reply.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle PL/SQL Procedures can return all the supported basic datattype( date,varchar2,number) plus complex ( records, tables, varray)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the pipelined function, in which you call the function as:

```
select ...
from   table(my_function(param1 => 1, ...))
```

See docs for details.

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarifying, ORACLE procedures cannot 'RETURN" per se, a SYS_REFCURSOR OUT parameter is more like changing the value of a variable reference inside the procedure.
Apart from `SYS_REFCURSOR`, if you are returning only one row of a table, say EMPLOYEE, you can also define a record as `EMPLOYEE%ROWTYPE` and use it as a `OUT` type.

Or like:

```
PROCEDURE pr_proc (v_input in number
                   v_emp_row out EMPLOYEE%ROWTYPE )
    IS
```